ex mode equivalent of ^R in powershell?
In bash and powershell.exe you can press ^R to bring up and search old commands.
I was wondering if vim had the same thing for ex mode and what the key combo is for that.

Do you really mean Ex mode? Or are you just talking about the command line?

@Rich Well it looks like Ex mode is a little different than pressing : in normal mode, but I meant :.

command history
In Vim you can do: : commandprefix Up
E.g.: :ech Up
Using the Up and Down will navigate through your command history for command that starts with ech (echo 'foo', echo 'bar', ...)
command-line window
You can also do q: and go to the command-line window and search for command ther using Vim functionality like /ech Enter.
Remark: The list of commands considered can be displayed using the history command.
e.g.:
To list the last 10 commands you type you can do:
:history : -10,


Also worth mentioning: :history. Unfortunately it doesn't support filtering yet. I'll fix that

Done. Now with patch 9.1.439 included, you can use :filter /pat/ :history

Great! I'll test it and I'll enrich the answer with the result of my test :-)
